# "[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified" when connecting to OracleDB using ODBC

Tags: oracle-database

I am trying to make an odbc connection to an oracle db from linux. When I login as root, it works. My root profile is as below:

```
more ~/.profile
export ODBCINI=/etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc/unixODBC
```

However, when I login as a regular user, I cannot do an odbc connections. I get this error:

```
[RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

I am not sure what is the problem here but I thought maybe I make root profile available to other users it may solve my problem. How do you present root profile to all of the other users? Any ideas what might be happening here?

Additional info:

this is my tnsnames.ora file looks like:

```
Data =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (LOAD_BALANCE = off)
      (FAILOVER = ON)
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server1.example.com )(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (service_name = Data)
    )
  )
```

this is what odbc.ini:

```
[Data]
Driver=Oracle
Description=Test
Trace=Yes
ServerName=//server1.example.com:1521/
Database=test
```

and this is ondbcinst.ini

```
[Oracle]
Description = Oracle ODBC Connection
Driver = /opt/oclient/instantclient_12_1/libsqora.so.12.1
Setup =
FileUsage =
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have one Database to connect, then you may do following

export TWO_TASK=db_SID

you may place this in /etc/profile and your work will be done.

Comment: You should not answer a question and ask another one in you question. Please post your question as a new one after checking whether it already has been asked here. Also you should avoid things like "thanks" and so on as this is discouraged by Stack posting guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that it's an issue with environment variables.

Run these lines manually right before invoking the application. The application MUST be invoked from command line right there.

```
export ODBCINI=/etc/unixODBC/odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc/unixODBC
```

If that works then you can add those lines to the system-wide `/etc/profile` file. Force users log-off and try again.

Comment: ok, that was one of the problem. After I did what you've recommended, I now get this error: [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 12162, message [unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Comment: Try running this as root: `set | grep ORACLE` and show what you get

Comment: nothing comes up

Comment: I just update my post with tnsnames and odbc config info, does that help?

Comment: Not sure. I must confess i'm no Oracle expert. Can a normal user read those files without permission problems?

Comment: yes, all of the files have 755